# Mongoid many to many relationship not working, what is wrong with my models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid4

I'm following the book *Ruby and MongoDB Web Development*, and and trying to follow the examples as much as possible, but for some reasons I'm not able to get it working.

This is what I have so far, models:

## app/models/book.rb

```
class Book
     include Mongoid::Document

     field :title, type: String
     field :publisher, type: String
     field :published_on,  type: Date

     field :votes, type: Array

     belongs_to :author
     has_and_belongs_to_many :categories

     embeds_many :reviews
end
```

## app/models/author.rb

```
class Author
     include Mongoid::Document

     field :name, type: String

     has_many :books
end
```

## app/models/category.rb

```
class Category
     include Mongoid::Document

     field :comment, type: String
     field :username, type: String

     has_and_belongs_to_many :books
end
```

So far so good, then in the rails console

```
irb(main):001:0> b  = Book.new(title: "Oliver Twist", publisher: "Dover Publications", :published_on => Date.parse("2002-12-30"))
=> #<Book _id: 53c9215c456d655abb000000, title: "Oliver Twist", publisher: "Dover Publications", published_on: 2002-12-30 00:00:00 UTC, votes: nil, author_id: nil, category_ids: nil>

irb(main):002:0> Category.create(name: 'Fiction')
=> #<Category _id: 53c92161456d655abb010000, name: "Fiction", book_ids: nil>

irb(main):004:0* Category.create(name: 'Drama')
=> #<Category _id: 53c92166456d655abb020000, name: "Drama", book_ids: nil>
irb(main):005:0> b.categories << Category.first
=> [#<Category _id: 53c92161456d655abb010000, name: "Fiction", book_ids: [BSON::ObjectId('53c9215c456d655abb000000')]>]

irb(main):006:0> b.categories << Category.last
=> [#<Category _id: 53c92161456d655abb010000, name: "Fiction", book_ids: [BSON::ObjectId('53c9215c456d655abb000000')]>, #<Category _id: 53c92166456d655abb020000, name: "Drama", book_ids: [BSON::ObjectId('53c9215c456d655abb000000')]>]

irb(main):007:0> b.save
=> true
irb(main):008:0> b
=> #<Book _id: 53c9215c456d655abb000000, title: "Oliver Twist", publisher: "Dover Publications", published_on: 2002-12-30 00:00:00 UTC, votes: nil, author_id: nil, category_ids: [BSON::ObjectId('53c92161456d655abb010000'), BSON::ObjectId('53c92166456d655abb020000')]>

irb(main):009:0> Category.first
=> #<Category _id: 53c92161456d655abb010000, name: "Fiction", book_ids: nil>
irb(main):010:0>
```

The category object does not get updated, what is happening? What I'm doing wrong?. help!

**Info:**
*Rails 4*,
*Mongoid 4*,
*Ruby 2.1*,
*MongoDB 2.6*

**Edit 1:**

line `embedded_in :book` removed unnecessary line from file *app/models/category.rb*.

Comment: You cant embed a habtm relation. Add `has_and_belongs_to_many :books` to model Category

Comment: Thanks, but actually that was a line I missed doing the copy&paste from my files. rechecked, and still not working.

Comment: What about this `embedded_in :book`

Comment: Yes, that line does not make sense for what it's intended, I have removed that line and tried again, and still is not working.

Comment: Strange. btw, did you reload the console, after the model changes?

Comment: Yes I did. I'll do it again just to be 200% sure.

Comment: @Santosh I reloaded the console again, and still it's not working :(. Although, records are being saved in mongodb correctly, the only thing that does not work properly is the relationship.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use autosave to support syntax of:

```
b.categories << Category.first
b.categories << Category.last
```

to do this, add this to your models

`has_and_belongs_to_many :books, autosave: true`

`has_and_belongs_to_many :categories, autosave: true`

to understand what happens, try following code in console without autosave:

```
b  = Book.new(title: "Oliver Twist", publisher: "Dover Publications", :published_on => Date.parse("2002-12-30"))
c1 = Category.create(name: 'Fiction')
c2 = Category.create(name: 'Drama')
b.categories << c1
b.categories << c2
b.save

c1.changed?
c2.changed?
```

It change parent object, but not save it automatically.

Comment: I did a fast research about this parameter and it turns out it was set as default in previous versions of mongoid but not anymore apparently. Thanks for providing a short and well elaborate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to get it to work, although, the way I did it, does not feel quite right to me.

Instead of

```
b.categories << Category.first
b.categories << Category.last
```

I used

```
b.category_ids << Category.first._id
b.category_ids << Category.last._id
```

Once the document is saved, the Category object gets updated as expected.

I must say, this does not feels quite correct, because many people use the other form, something have to be wrong with either me or the Mongoid gem.

Any further explanation is welcome and may be accepted as the correct answer.